Homology and Brouwer degree theory over: the quotient space obtained of the suspension of $S^1 \vee S^1$ identifying its endpoints.

Hi, everyone!

I think my solution isn't the more economic. Actually, I'm not satisfied, and to be honest I think I miscalculated the celular homology of
$$ X= \dfrac{(S^1 \vee S^1)\times[-1,1]}{(S^1\vee S^1)\times\{-1,1\}}$$
In my first celular decomposition I was drawing
$X$ as a "doubled croissant" with endpoints identified.

First, I did $A, B \subset X$ st $A \cup B=X$ and $A \cap B = (S^1 \vee S^1)\sqcup *$. We have: $H_n(A)\oplus H_n(B)$ is trivial for $n>0$, and $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ for $n=0$; $H_n((S^1\vee S^1)\sqcup *) \cong H_n(S^1)\oplus H_n(S^1)\oplus H_n(*)$ that is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ for $n=0$, $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, for $n=1$, and trivial for $n>1$.
And by Mayer-Vietoris in
$$\small  \cdots \to H_n((S^1\vee S^1)\sqcup *) \to H_n(A)\oplus H_n(B) \to H_n(X) \to H_{n-1}((S^1\vee S^1)\sqcup *) \to \cdots$$ So, for $n>2$ we have $H_n(X) \cong H_n(A)\oplus H_n(B)=0$. Also, $H_0(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_1(X)=\dfrac{Ker(\partial_1)}{Im(\partial_0)}\cong \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{1}}.$

Last edit: Now I get where I wronged about $H_1((S^1 \vee S^1)\sqcup *)\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$. This implies that $H_2(X)\not \cong 0$.
And I'm not too certain about my description of $d_n(e^k_\alpha)=\Sigma_\beta \lambda_{\alpha\beta}e^{k-1}_\beta$ using local (Brouwer) degree theory.
But thinking as the Example 0.8 of Hatcher's AT book  maybe could be easier to calculate everything about $X$ as $S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^1$.

This finish it!

Thanks for the answers!

Hi, welcome to the site. There's some missing context here we would want to see. For example, it sounds like you are trying to compute $H_\bullet(X)$ to solve some other problem; it also sounds like you're not sure of your computation, but you haven't shown us what you've done (so, we cannot help you if you have made a mistake). It would be good to edit your post to flesh it out a bit more

I'm pretty sure $H_1 = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_2 = \mathbb{Z}^2$ - at least I get this from Mayer-Vietoris by cutting the picture horizontally through the point (so each half is contractible, and the intersection looks like $S^1 \vee S^1$ plus a point). $H_1 = \mathbb{Z}$ makes sense to me - the generator comes from passing through the glued endpoint, and the loop from each original $S^1$ gives zero since it can be shrunk to the endpoint.

I misread the quotient description my bad, computed homology of the wrong space! @arkeet I agree with your results now. $H_\bullet(X)\cong(\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z^2,0,0,\cdots)$

If you're sufficiently convinced that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^1$ then that provides an easy check of whether your result's correct, since the homology of a wedge sum of spaces is the direct sum of the homologies of the summands. This tells you that what arkeet and FShrike computed is right.

Thank you all! And I get now where I wronged about $H_2$! I wrote sth that is completely wrong hahaha!! $H_1((S^1 \vee S^1)\sqcup *) \cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$

Another way to solve the problem is by taking a nice CW decomposition of your space. From the picture linked, the clear structure should be 1 0-cell, 3 1-cells, and 4 2-cells. These generate the following chain groups: $$C_2:=\mathbb{Z}_u\oplus\mathbb{Z}_v\oplus\mathbb{Z}_w\oplus\mathbb{Z}_z, C_1:=\mathbb{Z}_a\oplus \mathbb{Z}_b\oplus\mathbb{Z}_c, C_0:=\mathbb{Z}_p$$ with the following attaching maps $$\partial_0(p)=0;$$ $$\partial_1(a)=\partial_1(b)=\partial_1(c)=p-p=0;$$ $$\partial_2(v)=\partial_2(w)=a-b,\partial_2(u)=\partial_2(z)=b-c$$
$$\partial_n=0 \text{ for } n\geq3$$
Now computing homology $$H_0(X;\mathbb{Z})=\dfrac{ker\partial_0}{Im\partial_1}=\langle p \rangle=\mathbb{Z};$$
$$H_1(X;\mathbb{Z})=\dfrac{ker\partial_1}{Im\partial_2}=\langle a,b,c|b-c,a-b \rangle=\mathbb{Z}$$
$$H_2(X;\mathbb{Z})=\dfrac{ker\partial_2}{Im\partial_3}=\langle u-z,v-w \rangle=\mathbb{Z}^2$$
$H_n=0$ else.
